# Connect http API to https domain on AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ssl, flask-restful

I have a Web App with registered domain and it is running on AWS EC2. The domain is `https:\\abc.abc`. I have a flask API on the same instance where it running as a microservice. The API is running as `http:\\abc.abc`. Now when I try to connect to the API using the Web App with the registered domain it shows me
`ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.`
I have an idea that this is error is because of the
`https and http connection`
but I don't know how to solve it. Can someone please help?

In need for a somewhat detailed answer as this error is completely new for me.

Comment: Do you have ssl certificate for your domain?

Comment: I didn't buy the domain, and I don't have the access to see if I have ssl certificate or not.

Comment: So that's why you have `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` error.

Comment: I checked with my team they said that there is an SSL certificate for the domain.